# Tkinter: create an identification code from user input

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new in using python and tkinter and I'm stuck with my script, this one:

```
from openpyxl import *
from tkinter import *


wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Script\\try.xlsx') 

sheet = wb.active 


def excel(): 

    sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "name"
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "birth"
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = "gender"
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=4).value = "mobile"



def focus1(event): 
    birth_field.focus_set() 


def focus2(event): 
    gender_field.focus_set() 


def focus3(event): 
    mobile_field.focus_set() 


def clear():    
    name_field.delete(0, END) 
    birth_field.delete(0, END) 
    gender_field.delete(0, END)
    mobile_field.delete(0, END)

def insert(): 
    if (fame_field.get() == "" and
        birth_field.get() == "" and
        gender_field.get() == "" and
        mobile_field.get() == ""):

        print("empty input") 

    else: 
        current_row = sheet.max_row 
        current_column = sheet.max_column 

        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=1).value = name_field.get() 
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=2).value = birth_field.get() 
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=3).value = gender_field.get() 
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=4).value = mobile_field.get() 


        wb.save('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Script\\try.xlsx') 

        name_field.focus_set() 

        clear() 


if __name__ == "__main__": 

 root = Tk() 

root.configure(background='light grey') 

root.geometry("500x300") 

excel()
#label
name = Label(root, text="name", bg="light grey") 

birthdate = Label(root, text="birthdate", bg="light grey")

gender = Label(root, text="gender", bg="light grey")

mobile = Label(root, text="mobile contact", bg="light grey") 

#grid
name.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W) 
birthdate.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W) 
gender.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W) 
mobile.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W) 

#entry
name_entry = Entry(root) 
birthdate_entry = Entry(root) 
gender_entry = StringVar()
mobile_entry = Entry(root) 


name_entry.bind("<Return>", focus1) 


birthdate_entry.bind("<Return>", focus2) 


gender_entry.bind("<Return>", focus4) 


mobile_entry.bind("<Return>", focus5) 


name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx="100") 
birthdate_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx="100") 
gender_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx="100") 
mobile_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, ipadx="100") 


excel() 

submit = Button(root, text="Submit", fg="White", 
                            bg="Red", command=insert) 
submit.grid(row=12, column=1) 

root.mainloop()
```

What I need is to create a code from the user input like this: first two letter of the name, plus year of birth, age (that I need to calculate from the birthdate) and last two digits of mobile phone all separete with a "_" (e,g. na_2000_20_99). I'd like it to appear in a text wedge that the user can see but not edit and then save it in my excel file. Is it possible? Also my first choice for the gender option was to use Radiobutton but for some reason it keep gives me error and so I kept the text form. If somebody could help with my problems I will be very grateful.
Thank you all and have a nice day!

Comment: ***(e,g. na_2000_20_99)***: Read up on [Custom String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You Program had errors wile executing.
Try the following Code.
Birth date should be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD.

```
from openpyxl import *
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Script\\try.xlsx') 

sheet = wb.active
datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d'
class Mainframe(Frame):
    # Mainframe contains the widgets
##    global inv_cnt
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        global msg, inv_cnt
        excel()
        inv_cnt=1
        # *args packs positional arguments into tuple args
        # **kwargs packs keyword arguments into dict kwargs

        # initialise base class
        Frame.__init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs)
        # in this case the * an ** operators unpack the parameters

        name = Label(self, text="Name:", font=('times', 15),anchor='e').place(relx=0.05, rely=0.05, height=15, width=100)
        birthdate = Label(self, text="Birth Date:", font=('times', 15),anchor='e').place(relx=0.05, rely=0.15, height=15, width=100)
        gender = Label(self, text="Gender:", font=('times', 15),anchor='e').place(relx=0.05, rely=0.25, height=15, width=100)
        mobile = Label(self, text="Mobile:", font=('times', 15),anchor='e').place(relx=0.05, rely=0.35, height=15, width=100)

        self.name = StringVar(self)
        self.name.set('')
        self.name=Entry(self,textvariable = self.name, width=280, bg='WHITE')
        self.name.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.05, height=25, width=100)

        self.birthdate = StringVar(self)
        self.birthdate.set('')
        self.birthdate=Entry(self,textvariable = self.birthdate, width=280, bg='WHITE')
        self.birthdate.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.15, height=25, width=100)

        self.gender = StringVar(self)
        self.gender.set('')
        self.gender=Entry(self,textvariable = self.gender, width=280, bg='WHITE')
        self.gender.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.25, height=25, width=100)

        self.mobile = StringVar(self)
        self.mobile.set('')
        self.mobile=Entry(self,textvariable = self.mobile, width=280, bg='WHITE')
        self.mobile.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.35, height=25, width=100)

        # Proceed button
        self.Submit = Button(self, text='Submit', fg="White", 
                            bg="Red", command=self.insert)
        self.Submit.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.50,height=25,width=100)

        self.Output = StringVar(self)
        self.Output.set('')
        self.Output1 = Label(self, textvariable=self.Output, font=('times', 10),anchor='e', bg='WHITE').place(relx=0.05, rely=0.70, height=15, width=200)

        self.name.bind("<Return>", self.focus1) 


        self.birthdate.bind("<Return>", self.focus2) 


        self.gender.bind("<Return>", self.focus3) 

    def focus1(self, event): 
        self.birthdate.focus_set() 


    def focus2(self, event): 
        self.gender.focus_set() 


    def focus3(self, event): 
        self.mobile.focus_set() 


    def get_inv_count(self,value):
        global inv_cnt
        inv_cnt = value 


    def clear(self):    
        self.name.delete(0, END) 
        self.birthdate.delete(0, END) 
        self.gender.delete(0, END)
        self.mobile.delete(0, END)

    def insert(self):
        print(self.name.get(), self.birthdate.get(), self.gender.get(), self.mobile.get())
        if (self.name.get() == "" and
            self.birthdate.get() == "" and
            self.gender.get() == "" and
            self.mobile.get() == ""):

            print("empty input") 

        else: 
            current_row = sheet.max_row 
            current_column = sheet.max_column 

            sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=1).value = self.name.get() 
            sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=2).value = self.birthdate.get() 
            sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=3).value = self.gender.get() 
            sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=4).value = self.mobile.get()
            difference_in_years = relativedelta(datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime(datetimeFormat), datetimeFormat),
                                                datetime.strptime(self.birthdate.get(), datetimeFormat)).years
            self.Output.set("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}".format(self.name.get()[:2], self.birthdate.get()[:4], difference_in_years, self.mobile.get()[-2:]))
            wb.save('try.xlsx') 

            self.name.focus_set() 

            self.clear() 

def excel(): 

    sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "name"
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "birth"
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = "gender"
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=4).value = "mobile"


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        global value
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("MY GUI")
        self.geometry('800x250')
        self.resizable(0,0)
                # create and pack a Mainframe window
        Mainframe(self).place(x=0,y=0,height=250,width=800)
        self.mainloop()       

App()
```

Comment: Thank you it work perfectly! The only problem is that it doesn't seem to save the info in the excel file or I'm missing how to do so. Also  I've tried adding the radiobutton for the gender like this, but it isn't working '''select_gender= StringVar(self)
select_gender_m = Radiobutton(root, text="Male", value="male", var=option)
select_gender_f = Radiobutton(root, text="Female", value="female", var=option)'''

Comment: For this program to work, you need to create the Excel manually because you are trying to read it first.

Comment: @CarloMarrone you need to use `self` instead of `root` when you creating the Radiobutton